# How to collect images of a website efficiently while browsing it?

Tags: firefox, images, browser-addons, download

What I want to achieve is:

after browsing the web page,all images on this page is downloaded to a specified directory.

Better with firefox because I'm using it.

Comment: Usually, depending on confifurations, the images are cached inside some Firefox folder. You can go there and take them.

Answer (score 5):

The firefox [**DownThemAll!**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201) allows you to selectively filter and fetch from a page.
This includes the ability to select by file type (extension).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you mean something like this:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2503
??

Comment: Not compatible with current version of firefox. Last updated in 2008, and even then people are reporting it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If you choose 'Save Page As...' in Firefox and use the option 'Web Page, complete' it will save the page html and store all external documents (css, js, and images) in a separate folder.

Comment: Not for some ajax sites,you can try save gmail.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. In that case you probably will need to use an extension to do it. Search on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/ or try the one suggested by Ami.